# Compiling and linking with a different versions of gcc on linux

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, elf

I am planning to compile a static library (mylib.a) with gcc 4.7.1. I want to take the advantages of C++11, so -std=c++11 is used. The platform, where I compile this lib is x86_64 SLES 11 with glibc-2.8.

Then I want to link this static library on a legacy platform with a legacy code, therefore I must use gcc 4.1.2 for linking and compiling the legacy code. So in my library headers I will not use any C++11 specific code. Also I will link libstdc++.a from gcc.4.7.1. The platform, where I want to link mylib.a, libstdc++.a(gcc4.7.1) and the legacy object files is x86_64 SLES 10 with glibc-2.4.

I tried all of this mess with some dummy C++11 code (std::async()) in mylib.a and it worked. I think this is possible only becuase of the ELF requiriements. Am I thinking correctly, or ELF has nothing to do with it? What kind of errors should I expect if mylib.a will contain some truly complex logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Linux has a C++ Application Binary Interface (ABI)](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html), which has been around for a while. This means that the calling conventions and name mangling across compilers on Linux is fixed. Therefore, as long as the libraries are compatible, you should be able to compiler with different compilers (or different versions of the same compiler) and have code which correctly and reliably links together.

Not entirely the ELF requirements *per se*...

Answer (score 2):

GCC guarantees binary compatibility all the way back to some ancient version of 3. As long as the libstdc++ you're linking to has the new library features, there's no reason you can't use them. You will just have to stay away from the new language and library features in code compiled with GCC 4.1.2.